# Output BST in Nested Form

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I have to do inOrder, levelOrder, preOrder, and postOrder transversal of a BST.

Here's a small sample with in order

```
class BSTNode:
    def __init__ (self, x, L=None, R=None):
        self.data = x
        self.left = L
        self.right = R

class BST:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.root = None

    def insert (self, x):
        def recurse (p):
            if x<p.data:
                if p.left==None:
                    p.left = BSTNode (x)
                else:
                    recurse (p.left)
            else:
                if p.right==None:
                    p.right = BSTNode (x)
                else:
                    recurse (p.right)
        if self.root==None:
            self.root = BSTNode(x)
        else:
            recurse (self.root)

    def inOrder (self):
        print ("InOrder:    ", end="")
        def recurse(node):
            if node != None:
                recurse(node.left)
                print(node.data,end = " ")
                recurse(node.right)
        recurse(self.root)
        print( )

def main( ):
    T = BST( )
    L = eval(input ("Enter list: "))
    for x in L:
        T.insert(x)
    T.inOrder( )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main( )
```

Does anyone know how I should approach this? I have separate methods (Python) for each traversal right now and I am doing the level-order algorithm using a queue.

Comment: @mich97 you will want to use recursion to print the tree. The algo goes along the lines of: print `[`, print left child, print own value, print right child, print `]`.

Comment: This makes sense, I've added a display method and I insert into the tree instead of printing. I can get the brackets but how do I go about getting the nested list format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recurse as you did in `BST.inOrder`, but instead of printing them, make (and return) a list recursively. And it seems more sense to put recusive functions in `BSTNode`.

```
class BSTNode:
    def __init__(self, x, L=None, R=None):
        self.data = x
        self.left = L
        self.right = R

    def inOrder(self):
        ret = []
        if self.left: ret.append(self.left.inOrder())
        ret.append(self.data)
        if self.right: ret.append(self.right.inOrder())
        return ret

    def preOrder(self):
        ret = []
        ret.append(self.data)
        if self.left: ret.append(self.left.preOrder())
        if self.right: ret.append(self.right.preOrder())
        return ret

    def postOrder(self):
        ret = []
        if self.left: ret.append(self.left.postOrder())
        if self.right: ret.append(self.right.postOrder())
        ret.append(self.data)
        return ret
```

---

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, x):
        def recurse(p):
            if x<p.data:
                if p.left==None:
                    p.left = BSTNode(x)
                else:
                    recurse(p.left)
            else:
                if p.right==None:
                    p.right = BSTNode(x)
                else:
                    recurse(p.right)
        if self.root==None:
            self.root = BSTNode(x)
        else:
            recurse(self.root)
```

---

```
T = BST( )
for x in [5,3,7,2,4,6,8]:
    T.insert(x)
print(T.root.inOrder())
print(T.root.preOrder())
print(T.root.postOrder())
```

output:

```
[[[2], 3, [4]], 5, [[6], 7, [8]]]
[5, [3, [2], [4]], [7, [6], [8]]]
[[[2], [4], 3], [[6], [8], 7], 5]
```

I'll leave Level-Order traversal for your exercise.